# Learning about GPIOs

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2

I know this is not a question about a particular issue but I'm quite confused about the GPIO circuitry and pinout in general.

I am completely new to this field and have no expertise besides some little from school in electronics. I did quite some Python programming before but I wanted to actually "see" things reacting to code in the real world that's why I bought my RPi 2.

But after using some very simple code to control an LED, I moved on to control a button. That's where my problems started.

Can you guys help me with some webpages and videos where you have learned about the GPIOs? I have no idea why I have to declare a pull up/down and no idea what that even is and I don't know which pins have voltage on it which don't. I have no clue about what an I2C is or UART and all that stuff.

I hope you can understand this and don't blame me for posting this rather general question :)

Comment: I suggest you look through https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/  We don't know your abilities and it's a bit pointless pointing you to material which may not be understood.

Comment: I would add that you don't need to know it all at once If your project only uses a button and an LED you don't need to worry about I2C or UARTs. Instead work through projects and learn just what you need. You can find a list of well documented projects from beginner to advanced on the adafruit site https://learn.adafruit.com/category/learn-raspberry-pi and I have read and can recommend getting started with raspberry pi http://www.amazon.com/Getting-Started-Raspberry-Pi-Electronic/dp/1457186128/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451430199&sr=8-1&keywords=getting+started+with+raspberry+pi

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange community. Don't worry - I think there will be quite a few persons around here just at the moment who have just opened their Christmas presents and are now scratching their heads a little.  If you need a little more interaction with others (and your reputation is large enough 20+ I believe) you can drop in on the Chat rooms - [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) will be your place to start there!)

Answer (score 1):

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin7_gpio4

This link tells you all about the GPIO, such as the physical pin, BCM Pin, and even WiringPi pin. It also explains the purpose of each pin in detail.

This link explains how to collect input data from a button:
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/

Comment: Also, This link tells how to use LEDs and inputs COMBINED. 
http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-6-using-inputs-and-outputs-together-with-rpi-gpio-pull-ups-and-pull-downs


This is a lib that can be used to simplify GPIO.
http://wiringpi.com/